# Ubuntu 14.04 and Scroll Lock on gnome

Tags: 14.04, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-backlight

So I got this back-lit keyboard that uses scroll lock to toggle the lights. The problem was that it didn't work.

My problem was that I use gnome as my desktop.

Solution:

1. (Only for gnome users) `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false`
2. `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`

If you want it to work automatically, enter the command upon startup. I used `System > Preferences > Startup Applications` and add the command from #2 here.

Cheers.

Comment: the anwser should be put below, not inside the question section. And disabling gnome keyboard plugin, you will revert to default keyboard layout (so it will works only for US people).